# Java HashMap lookup failing on identical key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a small bug probably stemming from my misunderstanding of HashMap and it's killing me. I've included a small snippet of test code that illustrates the problem.

I omitted the Prefix class for conciseness, but my prefixes are just arrays of words. They are immutable, so when they are constructed they clone an array of strings passed into the constructor. `Hashcode()` and `equals()` methods are implemented so the conditionals pass. Essentially the problem is that I can only dereference the suffix list using prefix1 and not prefix2 (it returns null in the latter case.

FYI, my Hashmap is simply declared as:

```
// Stores mappings between "prefixes" (consecutive word phrases) and "suffixes" (successor words).
private Map<Prefix, ArrayList<String>> prefixSuffixPairs;
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
   ArrayList<String> suffixInList = new ArrayList<String>();
   suffixInList.add("Suffix1");
   suffixInList.add("Suffix2");

   String[] prefixWords1 = new String[] {"big", "the"}; 
   Prefix prefix1 = new Prefix(prefixWords1);

   String[] prefixWords2 = new String[] {"big", "the"}; 
   Prefix prefix2 = new Prefix(prefixWords2);

   prefixSuffixPairs.put(prefix1, suffixInList);

   if(prefix1.hashCode() == prefix2.hashCode()) {
      System.out.println("HASH CODE MATCH");
   }

   if(prefix1.equals(prefix2)) {
      System.out.println("VALUES MATCH");
   }

   ArrayList<String> suffixOutList = null;
   suffixOutList = prefixSuffixPairs.get(prefix2);
   suffixOutList = prefixSuffixPairs.get(prefix1);   

  public int hashCode() {

  int result = 1;
  for( int i = 0; i< words.length; i++ )
  {
      result = result * HASH_PRIME + words[i].hashCode();
  }

  return result;
  }

  public boolean equals(Prefix prefix) {

  if(prefix.words.length != words.length) {
     return false;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
     if(!prefix.words[i].equals(words[i])) {
        return false;
     }
  }

  return true;
  }
```

Comment: In the `Prefix` class, is the equals method overloaded or overrode?

Comment: show us `hashCode()` and `equals()` in your `Prefix` class

Comment: @AdrianShum He already said that the conditionals pass.

Comment: @Thomas If the signature of equals is `boolean equals(Prefix p)` then it won't work.

Comment: That's why we need to see how it is implemeneted to make sure it is implemented right

Comment: And that's what the `@Override` annotation is for. Always use it for methods you intend to override something. It would catch the `equals(Prefix p)` problem.

Comment: are you overriding hashcode() and equals() method

Comment: hmmm... Where's `prefixSuffixPairs.put(prefix2, suffixInList);`

Comment: @user2706534: That's redundant, as `prefix2.equals(prefix1)`

Comment: Java arrays do not implement `equals` and `hashcode` property. Are you using `Arrays.equals` and `Arrays.hashCode` in your methods?

Comment: @tobias_k the implementation of the methods is supposedly correct (asserted by the `if` conditionals above). Current thinking is that `equals` does not override the correct method.

Comment: Added the requested method implementations. Sorry about not adding them before, I figured they were pretty straightforward.  Basically I am manually comparing each array element.

Comment: @AlexisC. Right! Very good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public boolean equals(Prefix prefix) {
```

That does not override Object#equals (and thus is not used by the HashMap).

You are merely providing an unrelated method of the same name (overloading) -- but you could call that from the one below:

Try

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object prefix) {
```

The `@Override` is not strictly necessary, but it would have enabled the compiler to detect this problem if you had applied it to your first method (you get an error when your assertion to override is mistaken).

Comment: = _always_ use `@Override`.

Comment: That was it. Thanks, Thilo. I knew it was something boneheaded.

Comment: If they were to design Java again, `override` would probably a method modifier keyword like `final` and mandatory (not an optional annotation). It is in some newer languages. At least with a decent IDE, it fills in `@Override` for you.

Comment: Coming from a C++, C# background that's how I expected it to work.

Comment: I don't think it will work in C++. Not sure about C# but I doubt it

Comment: C++ introduced the override specifier in C++11